# Disable jquery datepicker calendar days, based on ajax php mysql table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I already have a  that works OK when I click on datepicker, with "beforeShowDay" function, I trigger a $.getJSON PHP procedure, that reads a MySQL table, create an array, and with another function, I disabled the days on the dataepicker calendar I want. This works ok, only for one calendar.  Now need I need to disble datepickers days, on multiple calendars that are generated on a PHP/MySql list. Here is my code, hope you understand me and give me a help !

```
<script>
   var unavailableDates = [];
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var myTour = "<?php echo $tourid ;?>";
    $.getJSON('closed_dates.php',{ 
         tourid: myTour
    },
     function(data) {
        unavailableDates = data;
   }); });

function unavailable(date) {
  ymd = date.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0"+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" +  ("0"+date.getDate()).slice(-2);
day = new Date(ymd).getDay();
if ($.inArray(ymd, unavailableDates) < 0) {
    return [true, "enabled", "Book Now"];
} else {
    return [false,"disabled","Sold Out"];
}
}  



enter code here$(function() {

  $('.iDate').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', 
      minDate: 0, 
      beforeShowDay: unavailable,

   });});</script>
```

This code works if only have one calendar, but I need to be able to disabled datepickers calendar day from a list, this is my PHP code

```
$query_tours = "Select * from tours where status ='A' and featured = 'Y' order by rand() limit 0,20" ;
$result_tours = mysql_query($query_tours);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_tours )) {
$tourid   = $row['recid'];
$tit_ing  = $row['tit_ing'];
(some html/css code here .....)
print "<input type='number' name='adults'>";
print "<input type='number' name='children'>";
print "<input type='text' name='tourdate' class='iDate' id='date$tourid'>";
}
```

So I do  not know how to pass the id value from php (list) and send as the value of 'myTour' on the  $.getJSON, for each datepicker calendar.

Hope, somebody understand me, best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tourid` in your sample is the `id` of `.iDate` minus the word `date`, which could be accessed like this:

```
$(this).id.substr(4);
```

Since you preload the `unavailableDates` it could be an array indexed by this `tourid`.

```
var unavailableDates = [];
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.iDate').each(function () { // For each iDate object
        var myTour = $(this).id.substr(4); // Get tourid from iDate id
        $.getJSON('closed_dates.php',{ 
            tourid: myTour
            },
            function(data) {
                unavailableDates[myTour] = data; // Add to the array
 }); }); });
```

Then inside the function `unavailable` (not a good name btw) you can index the `unavailableDates` array by the `id` of `this`, which was set as `'date$tourid'` by the back code.

```
function unavailable(date) {
    var myTour = $(this).id.substr(4); // Get the tourId
    ...
    if ($.inArray(ymd, unavailableDates[myTour]) < 0) {
    ...
}
```

Not that this will trigger as many ajax requests as there are calendars. Since you are preloading it would be much better to include the array directly in the first PHP page, like this:

```
print "<script>unavailableDates[$tourid]=$getDates(tourid);</script>";
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the first option, but only on the second click on datapicker, it update the unavailable days.  When I tried the second option, I receive an error message "tourid is no defined". What you mean with $getDates(tourid)?  Thank you for your time and your help, I have been with this issue for two days !!

Comment: Hi Ariel, I found the problem. I was missing "var" at myTour = $(this).id.substr(4); now, it works fine. Thank you very much for your help.